# Andengine Half black screen

Tags: android, camera, andengine

I am trying to develop a game with andengine. I create a camera, set its bounds and dimensions (720X1280) But when I run the app I see only the top part of the screen and the rest is black.

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    float ratio = (float) size.y / (float) size.x;
    GameSettings.CAMERA_HEIGHT = (int) (GameSettings.CAMERA_WIDTH / ratio);
    Constants.camera = new SmoothCamera(0, 0, GameSettings.CAMERA_WIDTH, GameSettings.CAMERA_HEIGHT, 500, 500, 0.1f);

    Constants.camera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
    EngineOptions en_op = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(GameSettings.CAMERA_WIDTH, GameSettings.CAMERA_HEIGHT), Constants.camera);
    en_op.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
    en_op.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
    return en_op;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("graph/");
    MyResources.SplashTextureRegion = MyResources.getTextureRegion(this, "splash.jpg", 720, 1280);
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: OK guys i found... it was the ratio calculation. I need to multiple width with the ratio not devide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys i found... it was the ratio calculation. I need to multiple width with the ratio not devide